# Outlook 2016 Exchange Error

Tags: mac, email, ms-office, exchange-activesync

I'm using the beta of the new Outlook 2016. When I try to add my own exchange account I constantly get the dialog telling me the server is being redirected. So then I tried to use the 'import' feature and grab the database from my Outlook 2011.

However! Once I hit the install button, I get this error: "the data contains an exchange 2010 SPP1 or older account". I can import the emails.. but I can't get the exchange server to sync. Is the company that supplies my exchange behind on their updates?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, according to this article Office 2016 only supports Exchange 2010 SP2 or higher: http://machow2.com/review-office-2016-mac-beta/